# Connecting 128x64 OLED to BIGTREETECH SKR mini E3

Tags: marlin, firmware, skr-mini-e3, bigtreetech

I'm trying to connect a 128x64 OLED display with the SH1106 driver for the BIGTREETECH SKR mini E3 printer controller board which uses the 32 bit STM32f103RC MCU.

Note that it works fine with my RAMPS 1.4 board but when I compile it on PlatformIO for the 32 bit controller, it doesn't work. Probing the pins on the board, the data and clock pins are floating. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Oliver, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Isn't this an OLED display instead of an LCD? Please add a photo of the graphical display to help others to answer your question.

Comment: Yeah, its an OLED, just changed the title. I've seen that Q/A, I believe it's quite old as they already implemented those changes with Marlin and it works without any modifications with the RAMPS 1.4 board. however, it doesn't seem to be working with my 32 bit controller which has the STM32f103RC MCU. I'm thinking it has something to do with the U8GLIB-HAL library.

Comment: Are you using the ARM version of the U8GLIB library? Please note that the U8GLIB is officially deprecated and not developed anymore. The developers have moved to U8G2, you can find many links of people using the OLED on the STM32. I cannot test this at the moment, my STM32 based controller board is being shipped...

Comment: yeah, marlin uses u8glib-hal for non atmega based boards

Comment: Bummer, I'll keep a watch on this Q and try myself when my board comes in. Please post an answer if you find a solution yourself! Good luck!

Comment: I also tried to connect an 12864 i2c oled screen, but I didn't succeed.
I don't think the library is good, or it's not good for stm32f103.
I found a link to a modified library ...
What stage are you at? did you manage to make skr e3 with oled, functional?